# Capture Zoom settings from AppleScript

Tags: applescript, microphone, zoom.app

On a Zoom call, I'd like to use AppleScript to determine the currently active Microphone and Speaker.

I can select a Mic option using https://github.com/raycast/script-commands/blob/master/commands/communication/zoom/toggle-mic.applescript but am unable to figure out how to read the values.

[image: Zoom settings]

Answer (score 0):

you can use GUI scripting for this, e.g. this gets you the current speakers:

```
    tell application "System Preferences"
        reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
    end tell

    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "System Preferences"
            tell tab group 1 of window "Sound"
                click radio button "Output"
                tell table 1 of scroll area 1
            set selected_row to (first UI element whose selected is true)
            set currentOutput to value of text field 1 of selected_row as text
            display dialog currentOutput
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
     end tell

     if application "System Preferences" is running then
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
     end if`
```

GUI script elements might be located differently on different MacOS releases.

Comment: Thanks - but this gets the current system output. Zoom has a unique capability where you can set the speakers distinct from the System output.

Comment: Which doesn’t change the system settings when on call? I have to try this later…  maybe [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46521/how-do-i-find-out-the-applescript-commands-available-for-a-particular-app) helps in finding which - if any - AppleScript commands Zoom offers.

Comment: Yes - that's why it's not as straight forward. Thanks for the Open Dictionary resource - didn't know that existed! Zoom doesn't have any official AppleScript commands. I think I'll need to investigate more of the GUI scripting.

Comment: @slartibartfast You really ought to test code before sharing it.  That said, your code is nice.  I would +1 had it been relevant to the OP's question.